# Get Double from JSON structure

Tags: json, scala, json4s

I've updated a JSON library and I'm having trouble extracting the value I want.

The JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "k1": {
    "k2 : {
      "k3" : 123
    }
  }
}
```

Previously, this did the trick:

```
(parse(json) \\ "k1" \\ "k2" \\ "k3").extract[Double]
```

did the trick, now it does not. Now I get the exception:

```
org.json4s.package$MappingException: Do not know how to convert JArray(List(JInt(123))) into double
```

I tried using `compact(render(parse(json) \\ "k1" \\ "k2" \\ "k3"))`, but that gave me the String `[123]`, which is not really what I want. How can I extract the value directly as a double?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `\\` accessor is incorrect here, as it walks the JSON recursively and extracts any `"k1"` it encounters, producing a `JArray`, thus the error.

You should either use `\` which accesses only one directly nested key of the JSON object, or `extract[List[Double]]` from your code.